# How do I provide null to BufferedReader's readLine() method using Eclipse

Tags: java, null, bufferedreader, readline

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int charCount = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;

        String line;
        try {
            while( (line = in.readLine()) != null ) {
                System.out.println(line);
                lineCount++;
                charCount += line.length();
                String[] words = line.split("\\W");
                wordCount += words.length;
            }
            System.out.println("charCount = " + charCount);
            System.out.println("wordCount = " + wordCount);
            System.out.println("lineCount = " + lineCount);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Straight to the point: How do I exit the above while-loop? I've read on another question that readLine() returns null when there is no more line left to read, but how do I do that using Eclipse's console?

The only way I can manage to break the loop is to add in cases, such as

```
if(line.length() == 2 || line.equals("exit")))
  break;
```

Comment: Have you tried ctrl-Z or ctrl-D?

Comment: You can also use Scanner class to read input from eclipse IDE.

Comment: I have to correct myself. It doesn't seem to work. Prior it probably exited because I had entered a string of length 2.

Comment: @Ankit I know, and I usually use Scanner. But I have to study java's IO classes, because I haven't yet. So I'd rather want to know whether I can write code like this.

Comment: Are you trying it when the console pane is in focus? And are you doing it after you have pressed return to enter the previous data?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ok. I think I've figured out how it works (it does, so I have to correct myself again). So I have the console focused, and I type in stuff. Works all fine. Then (console still focused) I type Ctrl+Z, nothing happens. I "unfocus" the console, focus it again. When I press Ctrl+Z now, it works ...

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to read a line, why do you need while loop?
or if you want multiple inputs to be taken then you should specify how many inputs are to be taken in first readline();
otherwise i hope below code will resolve your issue :)

public class TestRandomArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int charCount = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;

          try {
            String line = in.readLine();
            lineCount++;
            charCount += line.length();
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            wordCount += words.length;
            System.out.println("charCount = " + charCount);
            System.out.println("wordCount = " + wordCount);
            System.out.println("lineCount = " + lineCount);
         in.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hey, totally forgot to reply to your answer, sorry. Well, I didn't want to enter just a single line. I wanted to know how I could deliver 'null' to readLine() using Eclipse's command line.